# Relationship into relationship

Tags: relationships, related-entries, related

I have problem with related entries. I want to get related entries into a related entry. We are a travel agency and want to show selected travel packages in a "deals template".

Channels are:

deals, travel_packages, destinatios

Deals
    deal_01     relationship (to travel_packages)
    deal_01     relationship (to travel_packages) 
    deal_01     relationship (to travel_packages)
    deal_01     relationship (to travel_packages) 
    deal_01     relationship (to travel_packages)

travel_packages

```
date        text input
price       text input
taxes       text input
date        date
destination relationship (to destinations)
hotel       text input
```

destinations

```
pictures_name   text input
maps        text input
description textarea
```

In "deals" template we have 5 relationship fields than are related with travel_packages. In deals template we chose the deals that we want to show.

Then in the template we have the follow code:

{exp:channel:entries channel="deals"}
{related_entries id="deal_01"}
Date: {date} (travel_packages field)
Price: {price} (travel_packages field)

Here we want to show travel_packages relationship with destinations channel

we want to show
{title}
{pictures_name}
{maps}
Description: {description}
But those tags are from destinations channels.

{related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}

We tried to use related_entries again:

{related_entries id="destination"}
{title}
{pictures_name}
{maps}
Description: {description}
{/related_entries}

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which EE version are you using? The relationships fieldtype was replaced with a greatly improved version in 2.6.0. I would strongly recommend updating before attempting to mess with relationships of any level of complexity.

Comment: Indeed, it is crucial you advise which version of EE you are using as the answers pre- and post-ee.2.6.x are wildly different. But relatively simple. Please re-engage for an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing by the style of relationship tags you are using the best way to do this is to use an embed.

Steps:

1.) Create a template with the code for the destinations with an embed variable in the entry_id section.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="destinations" entry_id="{embed:eid}"}
     <h1>{title} Related to the Package Deal</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

2.) Put that embed inside your travel package related entries loop with the entry id of the package in a eid variable you pass to the embed variable.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="deals"} 
  {related_entries id="deal_01"}
     Date: {date} Price: {price}
     {embed="path/to/embed/template" eid="{entry_id}"}
  {/related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```